# How to learn the last directory entry in current path?

Tags: cmd

I am looking for shortest solution for the following problem:

I would like to learn the last directory entry in current path, so for *C:\Temp\Local* the function should return *Local*

I have come to the following solution but I wonder, if there is more shorter/optimal one:

```
@echo off

set dir=%CD%

:repeat

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in ("%dir%") do (
    if "%%b" == "" goto :end
    set dir=%%b
)

goto :repeat

:end
echo %dir%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

for %%* in (.) do @echo %%~n*
```

Comment: Could you please explain your solution? `%~n` is a filename, but what `%~n*` is? And we need a cycle just to populate `%*` (e.g. we can't do this trick with `%CD%`)?